# Scanning barcode containing space in Odoo POS causes issue

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Scan any product barcode in Odoo POS. Set quantity for the product as 3. Scan another product barcode which contains space inside barcode. (Scan the barcode "HB 5732" ,for instance, with a space between B and 5). On scanning the barcode, the quantity of the first product changes to 33.

This issue can be reproduced on runbot on Odoo v11. The issue can only be produced if the barcode is scanned by a barcode scanner (Issue was produced using Honeywell MS7120 Orbit Laser Barcode scanner). Using debug window and entering the same barcode causes no issue.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be appreciated.